# Функция mail() письмо не прилетает

Tags: php, email

Функция mail() возвращает значение тру и происходит переадресация. Но письма на почте нету.В спаме нету,отправляю с хоста,SMTP присутствует.В чем может быть проблема?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.phtml" method="post">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Имя"><br/>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Емаил"><br/>
            <input name="phone" placeholder="Телефон"><br/>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name']) and !empty($_POST['email']) and 
!empty($_POST['message'])) {
$headers = 'From: ****' .
    'Replay-to: *****' .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$theme = 'Новое сообщение';
$letter = 'Данные сообщения:\r\n';
$letter .= 'Имя: ' . $_POST['name'] . '\r\n';
$letter .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '\r\n';
$letter .= 'Телефон: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '\r\n';
$letter .= 'Сообщение: ' . $_POST['message'] . '\r\n';
if (mail('*****', $theme, $letter, $headers)) {
    header('Location: thankyou.phtml');
} else {
    header('Location: /');
}
}else{
header('Location: /');
}
```

Comment: Может `Reply-to:` вместо `Replay-to:`. А вообще надо админам хостинга писать.

Comment: В теме удобнее, если будет что-то вроде 'Сообщение от <email>'. Кстати, письмо может не проходить, если поля From и Reply-to не содержат корректных e-mail-адресов. Например `Message From Site <no-reply@mysite.com>`. SMTP-сервер такое сообщение может пропустить, а вот POP3-сервер откажется принять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To:
> webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';

или так

> $headers  = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
>
> $headers .= 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
>
> $headers .=   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
>
> $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

Comment: Переделал теперь отправляет но почему то закидывает в спам можно ли сделать так что бы не закидывало в спам?

Comment: И почему то \r\n не работают.Вот такое письмо прилетает Данные сообщения:\r\nИмя: Dulana Donatan Donkil\r\nEmail: daizer777@gmail.com\r\nТелефон: +45 777 777 777\r\nСообщение: Hello\r\n

Comment: Указывайте 'Content-type' - обновил в ответе. А по поводу спама - это зависит от вашего ящика. Но первым делом смотрите какой майл указываете как отправителя и какой майл вашего домена, с которого отправляете. В идеале майл отправителя должен быть на том же домене, с которого отправляете письмо.